# Dataframe interger loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to run a loop on a very large dataframe where I add the values of two rows together

```
for i,r in table0.iterrows():
   table0.add(r(['x'], r+1['x'])
```

But I get the below error and I am not sure how to go about fixing it

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

First few of the x values I want to add ***562, 563, 568, 569, 566*** (tried to add the table, but it wouldn't format nicely)

What I want to happen

562+563

563+568

568+569

569+566

Comment: `r+1['x']` is running `r + (1['x'])`, which is invalid. What are you really trying to do? Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Sorry, very new to coding, like I said I am trying to add the values of two rows together i.e. row1 + row2, row 2 + row 3, row 3 + row 4, etc

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your data?

Comment: Sure, edited the main post with a screen shot

Comment: Please no screenshots, only data than one can copy/paste (text/code) and don't forget to provide the **matching expected output**

Comment: Couldn't add a screen shot anyway, added the data and what I expect to happen, sorry I am new to all this, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
df.shift(-1)
```

So in my code it was

```
table0['Sum_x'] = table0['x'].shift(-1) - table0['x']
```